# Approach for SharePoint file upload workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow, sandbox-solution

I'm working on a project that is basically a file upload "wizard" that basically does the following:

1. Entry form to select document library and enter some basic info.
2. Enter additional library-specific information.
3. Tie in some calendar events.

My goals are:
 - Create this as a sandbox solution using Visual Studio
 - Avoid hacks and reinventing existing functionality as much as possible.

Some SP features I have run across that might be useful:
 - Content organizer feature.
 - Association forms.
 - Declarative workflows.

Possible approaches I've considered:

1. A content organizer library that kicks off a workflow on submission. Not sure what the user experience for this would be like. Really hoping to keep to a single link -> Next -> Next -> Done kind of approach.
2. A declarative workflow with custom actions containing all the complexity.
3. An association form in front of the built-in document upload form for each library with a follow-on association form for calendar events.

Is this feasible and if so which approach is simplest?

Comment: Do you really need the workflow to upload the file?  This sounds like a simple list form, with some mandatory fileds, and file attachments allowed?  Perhaps turn it around...allow user to pick the document library when they create the list item, then use a workflow to move it to that library?

Comment: @BlueChippy - Yes, I'm definitely open to these. This essentially sounds like #3 with the document upload library. Have been having a bit of a challenge generating the forms and figuring out how to populate the list of other libraries.

Comment: duplicate [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54482/appoach-for-sharepoint-2010-file-upload-workflow](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54482/appoach-for-sharepoint-2010-file-upload-workflow)

Comment: @jubinPatel - yes, I know. I posted both of these since this one was not getting much of a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've come to my own conclusions on this. I've decided to go with a Drop Off library as part of the Content Organizer built-in feature (#1 above). This appears to be the simplest approach so far since I can do the majority through configuration in the Entity.xml files of the features. Many of the other methods I tried seems like they would require functionality not available in a Sandbox solution.

In order to achieve this, I defined site columns and added them to custom Document Type, then added this Document Type to all libraries. Using the Drop Off library, I can define rules to move the file based on one of the fields in the custom Document Type. I'm hoping to do any follow-up steps as a workflow that kicks off on the Drop Off library when a file is uploaded or as an Associated Form.